# How can I strip all html using a preg_replace?

Tags: regex, preg-replace

strip_tags only catches tags that have a beginning and end tag.  With the strings I'm working with it's causing issues and I need to removed all HTML tags.

Comment: `strip_tags` should remove all HTML tags. What input are you trying that's not being stripped, exactly?

Comment: Generally, parsing XML/HTML by regular expressions is not considered a good thing. Especially HTML from user input / untrusted source should always be translated into well-formed XML and manipulated with proper XML tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to *clean* some HTML, I would suggest using a *real* HTML parser, like [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Generally speaking, trying to manipulate HTML with regex tends to end badly...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$html = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor <br>sit amet, <br />consectetur adipisicing elit</p>';
echo strip_tags($html);

?>
```

... prints:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
>   consectetur adipisicing elit

Comment: http://www.starcraft-source.com/strategy/article/view/?id=205

Look at Micro in the first paragraph you can mouseover it and see the definition you can see paragraph tags that exist within the definition.

Comment: @Webnet: That proves nothing if you don't show us the original string. If you run strip_tags() on the current contents of the title attribute, tags do get removed.